# How do I use a Rack middleware only for certain paths?

Tags: ruby, rack, middleware

I'd like to have `MyMiddleware` run in my Rack app, but only for certain paths.  I was hoping to use `Rack::Builder` or at least `Rack::URLMap`, but I can't quite figure out how.

This is what I thought would work, but doesn't:

```
# in my rackup file or Rails environment.rb:
map '/foo' do
  use MyMiddleware, { :some => 'options' }
end
```

Or, better yet, with a Regexp:

```
map /^foo/ do
  use MyMiddleware, { :some => 'options' }
end
```

But `map` seems to demand an app at the end; it won't fall back on just passing control back to its parent.  (The actual error is "`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`" from when Rack tries to turn the end of that `do...end` block into an `app`.)

Is there a middleware out there that takes an array of middlewares and a path and only runs them if the path matches?

Comment: stupid typo -- thanks for correcting that, AnthonyWJones! ::hangs head in shame::

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could have MyMiddleware check the path and not pass control to the next piece of middle ware if it matches.

```
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize app
    @app = app
  end
  def call env
    middlewary_stuff if env['PATH_INFO'] == '/foo'
    @app.call env
  end

  def middlewary_stuff
    #...
  end
end
```

Or, you could use URLMap w/o the dslness. It would look something like this:

```
main_app = MainApp.new
Rack::URLMap.new '/'=>main_app, /^(foo|bar)/ => MyMiddleWare.new(main_app)
```

URLMap is actually [pretty simple to grok](http://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1785a44d3a97cb38b4b197b5cb66bd86093bf438/lib/rack/urlmap.rb).

Comment: [Rack::URLMap](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/URLMap.html) unfortunately doesn't support using regular expressions as the location (hash key) part, so the second part of this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't work because `@app` doesn't exist in the right scope:

```
# in my_app.ru or any Rack::Builder context:
@app = self
map '/foo' do
  use MyMiddleware
  run lambda { |env| @app.call(env) }
end
```

But this will:

```
# in my_app.ru or any Rack::Builder context:
::MAIN_RACK_APP = self
map '/foo' do
  use MyMiddleware
  run lambda { |env| ::MAIN_RACK_APP.call(env) }
end
```

`Rack::Builder` strips the first argument to `map` off the front of the path, so it doesn't endlessly recurse.  Unfortunately, this means that after that path prefix is stripped off, it's unlikely that the rest of the path will properly match other mappings.

Here's an example:

```
::MAIN_APP = self
use Rack::ShowExceptions
use Rack::Lint
use Rack::Reloader, 0
use Rack::ContentLength

map '/html' do
  use MyContentTypeSettingMiddleware, 'text/html'
  run lambda { |env| puts 'HTML!'; ::MAIN_APP.call(env) }
end

map '/xml' do
  use MyContentTypeSettingMiddleware, 'application/xml'
  run lambda { |env| puts 'XML!'; ::MAIN_APP.call(env) }
end

map '/' do
  use ContentType, 'text/plain'
  run lambda { |env| [ 200, {}, "<p>Hello!</p>" ] }
end
```

Going to `/html/xml` causes the following to go to the log:

```
HTML!
XML!
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2009 17:41:42] "GET /html/xml HTTP/1.1" 200 13 0.3626
```

That is, the app mapped to `'/html'` strips of the `'/html'` prefix and the call now matches the app mapped to `'/xml'`.